# S3 PreSigned URL is cut when sent in an email

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, boto3

I have a script which generates an S3 PreSigned URL and sends it in an email.
The script works fine, but when the email is sent, it adds a new-line to the URL, which breaks it and makes it unusable in the email.

**The only packages installed:**

- boto3
- Jinja2

**The script:**

```py
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

# AWS
my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'eu-west-1'
)
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=my_config)
bucket = "name of bucket"

# Jinja2
loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=loader)
email_template = env.get_template('test_template.html')

def create_presigned_url(bucket, object_name, expiration=259200):
    response = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': object_name}, ExpiresIn=expiration)
    return response

def sendEmail(download_link):
    toEmail = 'me@email.com'
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    title = 'Test email'
    sender = 'me@email.com'
    rendered_template = MIMEText(email_template.render({'download_link':download_link}), 'html')
    msg['Subject'] = title
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = toEmail
    receivers = toEmail
    msg.attach(rendered_template)
    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('mail.server.com', 25)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
        print ("Successfully sent email")
        smtpObj.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print (e, "Error: unable to send email")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    selectedFile = 'file.txt'

    # Download link
    downloadURL = create_presigned_url(bucket, selectedFile)
    # print(downloadURL)

    # Send email
    sendEmail(downloadURL)
```

**Results**

When I run the script, for some reason I get a newline somewhere inside of this long URL, which breaks the URL:

[image]

Here's the source from Outlook:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">Download link: https://redacted/9%2FJOUw%3D&amp;x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEH0aCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJHMEUCIEBMYHD9wKhOfrR00jTv7RIcsRe3NbOU31QniJpEdps8AiEAi377qRmvQQXb5dXhRGJcXulFhRunGTSd0GRyGXHR2kMqzAQIdhAEGgwzNTgyODkxNTgxMTIiDH3bqAZMxVyKH3f6xyqpBL40WhPQMShoV8x1epn85Ml6qQ8Y1xdHe16xyoMWKqylbLGrndMFtYyOgs6LAlDvGJPrcF9xymGf8BqGsGHwCuWGdEcisxvwR%2FUoigjHBXP55fHpF%2FXnVupCRYDIVA5N%2BVOKW5%2BcljVN9KC3RKKvEeUncTGnXIaW5UHNAPiFSrgbbj9X%2FyBptkFmj5f4x2Zblm8crQS0rMTveCuoki3E06NO%2FKiDNiJQpF1vVphb%2F0spIR3CUxSx9HJHjvRBWTWQn9bmmT8rhp0lx%2Bzx9RLlpmE6hRRF6KBpNW%2B86y3EB%2BtMxVBuEhC5M1rCyjou6efK%2FA96wuwBN%2FmjD663vyZipiOGrj4yOFIMPklBu4L1SnfkxhZN8%2BNWXzwc%2B%2B5%2FNfL%2BVzyFpWS7TbGIM4A9TEvL3bPlgafvIl%2Fi24MOrN47UshpdpHGAjG20PBr0cbi75G7D%2B3UoSn%2Bzp0hZkAEACnwWtWtzEpVWbwatx%2FL1T8XF43o8OiKWqCfVxBjoZSc1itxRDOUqonYbCGY2Y0NlkXpvpHBZMcg7530dIFRBBxhTZo4RVXqkymTM4hEvDUw74R%2BDovr%2F%2BG5ji52Wpcng
 954ESTpzMjOtuBXKcPtmEWTqx4au99ZP8lxbqKjq3BO%2FJLqrzTCPSEs6CTv7YbtzUqQ0r%2BkFyAU2RnpTTcYPJ5SD8ytlb4qUHb5RhEcn3bbJ5fsIRx%2B6q3LrhWkorDNKp5jh6oth1roRxXQM0swgN%2BzmwY6qQGnjWLAgUSUB9yf3heEdiFZo4DnC7ipW6BgsnkoeZJcPz5Ysx5PG4kzelCP89AsXQGD%2BtFqweusgWJVLo3dfyK3iLJ5myohn7mjSf1YVE%2B5CGlajc2HZl%2BoUOhI5gMMxpFXtpIL6jgTyY5r6ZwCKZ9g1afHO1kUF4VYir2M2BWYHTcB%2Bu8TANzoc15RJih8XmE%2FAWd%2FMQM7SQOQxsbmCiRSv5AeYMuok%2FSw&amp;Expires=1668345190
```

I tried:

- using `| safe` inside of my Jinja2 template.
- I tried using the href HTML tag, no dice.

I don't know what else I can check and have no idea why it's happening. People mentioned this might be the cause: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1

Comment: just strip newline character using `str.strip()`? Not very smart move, but will work

Comment: @PavelShishmarev thanks for the suggestion, but the newline is not added during the runtime of the script. When I simply print the rendered email, there is no newline, only once it is delivered to the email client.

Comment: pls add jinja template to the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is related to max line length defined in the "Internet Message Format" RFC document [5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt)

> 2.1.1. Line Length Limits
>
> There are two limits that this standard places on the number of characters in a line. Each line of characters MUST be no more than 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding the CRLF.
>
> ...
>
> The more conservative 78 character recommendation is to accommodate the many implementations of user interfaces that display these messages which may truncate, or disastrously wrap, the display of more than 78 characters per line, in spite of the fact that such implementations are non-conformant to the intent of this specification (and that of [RFC2821] if they actually cause information to be lost). Again, even though this limitation is put on messages, it is encumbant upon implementations which display messages

Your line (with redacted information) has 961 characters, so adding those redacted information I assume you go over that limit of 998 characters.

Now, my thinking is that your local SMTP server is not splitting the line but the one on Amazon server may do that.

I assume that reducing the line length is not really an option :)

I would try with changing the markup, because now Outlook is looking for links and highlighting them in your message. I would try to add html markup for that with new line character inside, which hopefully will be ignored by the email client.

```html
<a href="https://redacted/9%2FJOUw%3D&amp;x-amz......
........">Download link</a>
```

Comment: That's also what I proposed in a now-deleted previous version of the OP's question. Looks like it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed I already tried it and it doesn't work. The whole premise of this thread was wrong I guess. It seems like the difference between the server is that on my WSL instance the PreSigned URL is 1003-1005 chars long, while the one on the server is 1400+ chars long, which is weird. I wish I could shorten the URL, but it seems to be the way PreSigned URLs are generated be default.

Comment: Have you tried using html <a> markup with new line in href? This wasn’t working neither?

Comment: I tried: `Download link: <a href="{{ download_link }}">Click here for access to this file</a>`

Comment: It seems like moving to SES instead of using our own SMTP server resolves the issue. The templated email looks fine and the URL is not broken. I think I will be closing this issue :)

Comment: Great news. Since with the same config there are differences between email servers I think the line length was an underlying issue.

Comment: Yep, just confirming that using a templated email with SES fixed the issue. URL is not broken even with an HTML template and the href tag for the URL. Kinda weird stumbling on an issue such as this, I wonder how many people used a script to send emails with an S3 PreSigned URL :) Thanks for the assistance everyone.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your jinja template to get something like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
Download link: 
<a href="https://redacted/9%2FJOUw%3D&amp;x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEH0aCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJHMEUCIEBMYHD9wKhOfrR00jTv7RIcsRe3NbOU31QniJpEdps8AiEAi377qRmvQQXb5dXhRGJcXulFhRunGTSd0GRyGXHR2kMqzAQIdhAEGgwzNTgyODkxNTgxMTIiDH3bqAZMxVyKH3f6xyqpBL40WhPQMShoV8x1epn85Ml6qQ8Y1xdHe16xyoMWKqylbLGrndMFtYyOgs6LAlDvGJPrcF9xymGf8BqGsGHwCuWGdEcisxvwR%2FUoigjHBXP55fHpF%2FXnVupCRYDIVA5N%2BVOKW5%2BcljVN9KC3RKKvEeUncTGnXIaW5UHNAPiFSrgbbj9X%2FyBptkFmj5f4x2Zblm8crQS0rMTveCuoki3E06NO%2FKiDNiJQpF1vVphb%2F0spIR3CUxSx9HJHjvRBWTWQn9bmmT8rhp0lx%2Bzx9RLlpmE6hRRF6KBpNW%2B86y3EB%2BtMxVBuEhC5M1rCyjou6efK%2FA96wuwBN%2FmjD663vyZipiOGrj4yOFIMPklBu4L1SnfkxhZN8%2BNWXzwc%2B%2B5%2FNfL%2BVzyFpWS7TbGIM4A9TEvL3bPlgafvIl%2Fi24MOrN47UshpdpHGAjG20PBr0cbi75G7D%2B3UoSn%2Bzp0hZkAEACnwWtWtzEpVWbwatx%2FL1T8XF43o8OiKWqCfVxBjoZSc1itxRDOUqonYbCGY2Y0NlkXpvpHBZMcg7530dIFRBBxhTZo4RVXqkymTM4hEvDUw74R%2BDovr%2F%2BG5ji52Wpcng954ESTpzMjOtuBXKcPtmEWTqx4au99ZP8lxbqKjq3BO%2FJLqrzTCPSEs6CTv7YbtzUqQ0r%2BkFyAU2RnpTTcYPJ5SD8ytlb4qUHb5RhEcn3bbJ5fsIRx%2B6q3LrhWkorDNKp5jh6oth1roRxXQM0swgN%2BzmwY6qQGnjWLAgUSUB9yf3heEdiFZo4DnC7ipW6BgsnkoeZJcPz5Ysx5PG4kzelCP89AsXQGD%2BtFqweusgWJVLo3dfyK3iLJ5myohn7mjSf1YVE%2B5CGlajc2HZl%2BoUOhI5gMMxpFXtpIL6jgTyY5r6ZwCKZ9g1afHO1kUF4VYir2M2BWYHTcB%2Bu8TANzoc15RJih8XmE%2FAWd%2FMQM7SQOQxsbmCiRSv5AeYMuok%2FSw&amp;Expires=1668345190">Download link</a>
```

as you didn't add `<a href=` your link is interpretated as long text => and in long text editor can add line breaks